# Can we use addEventListener in vscode extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I have been trying to use addEventListener in my own vscode extension. Basically, I want to catch if the user press certain key, say esc, then do something. Can anyone show me a basic working example in extension? Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That's not possible, no. You cannot access the DOM in vscode directly.

Comment: Thank you @Mike Lischke for your comments. If addEventListener is not possible, what would be a feasible way to achieve the action in the original question? Should I use some vscode default API? Thank you!

Comment: You cannot subscribe to single key strokes. Instead you would act on actions triggered via a menu, a hotkey or the command pallet.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Saved me a lot of time. :) @Mike Lischke